# SF text field Password masking

Tags: custom-field, configuration, passwords

I have a text field and it needs to be masked. So, what are out options?

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate about "masked"? From who and where do you want to protect it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, I have text field basically named as "XYZ Password" and I want this to be a masked field. And I want this to be reflected on a payment gateway.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to create Encrypted field shown as below

[image: Encrypted field creation]

The options you shown on your screenshot is only for documentation purposes for your organization to determine what is considered "sensitive" or in compliance

Comment: Thanks for your answer @compski. This helps to clear my head at least.

Comment: The password field I need to create is for a payment gateway

Comment: ok do upvote my answer and/or accept it as best answer if it solves your question! thx